# Class Declaration - Unclear object type

Tags: java

If there is a declaration of

`Human tom = new Athlete();`

and `Athlete` is a subclass of `Human`, which object type is `tom`?

For `tom.method1()` and there is a `method1()` in both classes, ie. `Athlete.method1()` overrides `Human.method1()`,

Which `method1()` do we use? The one from the `Athlete` class or the `Human` class?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between Human tom = new athlethe();  and athlete tom = new athlethe();

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The actual type of `tom` is `Athlete`. However because the declaration of `tom` specifies `Human`, you can only access methods defined on `Human` (and its super-classes).

If a method on `Human` is overridden in `Athlete`, eg. `method1()`, then the implementation on `Athlete` is the one that is called.

If you were to declare `tom` to be of type `Athlete` (as per the question in your comment), then the actual type of `tom` does not change. However, you can now access methods that are only defined on `Athlete`.

Answer (score 0):

The object is always based on the class you created it (and you create an object by using the keyword `new`). In this case, you would have an object of `Athlete` class, that would call the `method1()` from `Athlete` as well, even if `Human` has its own version of the method.

If there was no `method1` on `Athlete` then you would get the inherited method from its superclass.

Answer (score 0):

The reference is of the parent type, but the object is of child type.

In this case only the **overridden methods of the child class, other methods and Instance variables in parent class** are visible to the reference and the other methods in child class will not be visible.

You can get clarified here
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm

Answer (score 0):

In this tom is a type of Athlete object. Athlete.method1 overrides the method in super class.If there is no method in Athlete class then it will call super method